# What is the best way to check writers blog before making them publicly available with Django?

Tags: python, django, backend

Recently, I have been practicing Django with creating a newspaper project. I wanted to create an environment where an author writes a blog, a superuser or somebody superior checks that block and approves it before publicly publishing them on the website. What are the ways to achieve it?
Should I create a separate app for it or maybe a separate page that will  only be available for superusers

Comment: A "separate app"? Separate from what? What do you already have? You can just put a status "pending approval" on the posts when the author submits them and use the django admin site for your super users to review the posts and change the status to "approved". But this isn't a specific programming problem, at least not focused enough for SO. Please show what you already have and what specific issue you're facing.

Comment: @dirkgroten, thanks for suggesting "pending approval". I wanted to create a separate app that will only be dedicated to checking, editing, commenting and approving the blogs. For example, if a writer writes a blog it will be posted on the URL of the new app which will only be accessible to the super users and the writer itself. I am still learning Django and was told that creating a separate app for each task is a good practice. Now, I can find more practical implementations with googling the pending approval, thanks for the hint

Comment: Not sure if a separate app makes sense. A separate app makes sense if you have separate models that are relatively independent of your blog. Which I don't think is necessary here. The fact that only superusers are allowed to approve/edit and comment on posts and that urls are maybe in their own namespace doesn't mean you need another app.

Comment: Unless you make a Approval model that is generic and can be used for any kind of approval.